# Problem using fn_listextendedproperty, Why does this query error on the fourth column on MSSQL2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

**If you're just going to vote this down and not tell me how to do better**, what's the  point? How can I learn to make the question better if you vote -1 and not leave me a comment.

```
select
   u.name,
   o.name,
   case (o.type) when 'S' then 'SYSTEM TABLE' else 'TABLE' end,
   (select convert(varchar(8000), value) from ::fn_listextendedproperty(NULL, 'user', u.name, 'table', o.name, null, null) where name = 'MS_Description') as coln
from
   sys.sysobjects o
   join sys.schemas  u on (u.schema_id = o.uid)
where
   o.type in ('U', 'S')
   and u.name = "something here"
order by 1, 2
```

Is there a simple fix to make it work or is it all F'ed up?

The error is:

```
SQLSTATE = 42000, Microsoft SQL Native Client, Incorrect Syntax near ‘u’
```

This [help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179853.aspx) for the function is virtually useless.

This seems like a very anti-sql, anti-normalization of data, pretty obtuse way of storing table comments.

Why isn't there comments column on a all_tables view?

**Update**

hard coded values in the function work fine, passing the results of the query in, do not. I've never seen anything like this before.

** Update II **

I replaced the 2005 native driver with the 2007 native driver and it no longer errors out, but it returns **ZERO** tables. ODBC works fine.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Rather non specific... just says there's a problem at "u." and management studio puts it in the 4th col def....

Comment: That SQL Native Client error is a bit odd. Do you know if the application which is running this query was originally written for SQL Server 2005? If so, the connection string may be out of date; it should look something like:

Provider= SQLNCLI10.1;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;  Trusted_Connection=yes;

If the app was originally written for 2005, the provider will be different.

That's the only thing I can think of-- the updated query runs OK for me (though it returns nothing)

Comment: Ken, that's a great tip. The connection isn't in the app, it's just using a conenction in the pc's data sources. But I was using a native connection, which could have out of date drivers, right? If I use ODBC, it should pass through fine, no?

Comment: Yep, changed it to ODBC and it worked. It's gotta be the local drivers on the PC are 2005 drivers, and doesn't understand this syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you use CROSS APPLY instead of a nested SELECT?

```
select
   u.name,
   o.name,
   case (o.type) when 'S' then 'SYSTEM TABLE' else 'TABLE' end,
   convert(varchar(8000), ex.value) as coln
from
   [%CATALOG%.]sys.sysobjects o
   join [%CATALOG%.]sys.schemas  u on (u.schema_id = o.uid)
   cross apply ::fn_listextendedproperty(NULL, 'user', u.name, 'table', o.name, null, null) ex
where
   o.type in ('U', 'S')
[  and u.name = %.q:OWNER%]
and ex.name = 'MS_Description'
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: The problem might be with those %CATALOG% tokens-- I'm not familiar with them. Are they a new feature in SQL Server 2008? They look like placeholders that are intended to be expanded by some kind of pre-processor. Are you using such a thing? When I take them out, the query parses correctly.

Comment: Thanks Ken, you're right, they are preprocessor macro expansions. I don't know what got added there. That, might just be the problem. I'll see what is getting added.

Comment: that's not it... we removed those before running, let me clarify in an edit

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bad open square bracket:

```
[  and u.name = %.q:OWNER%]
```

should be

and u.name = [%.q:OWNER%]

And I agree on those token things, I've never seen them before and I bet a lot of others haven't, either. I recommend replacing them.

I'd also fix that "order by 1,2" and use column names instead.

Comment: that's a macro expansion as Ken pointed out. they aren't what gets executed.

Comment: So the square bracket was supposed to be fore the "and"?

Comment: The client which generates the sql, would be expanding the macro.

Comment: Stephanie, I got that. The question was, in that macro, was the "[" supposed to be in front of the "and"? It said "[  and u.name = %.q:OWNER%]"

Comment: Doesn't matter... that's just a pass through. It won't touch it, it's text. The only MACRO that would be touched exists between %'s.